# How to find the distance confidence between the sum of random variables and a given target value?

Tags: machine-learning, random-variable, stochastic-processes, random-generation

Given a distribution $X$($E[X]$, $Var[X]$) and a target value T, I am wondering whether there is a bound on $P(|\sum_{i=1}^{i=N}X_i - T| < \epsilon)$.

For example, $P(|\sum_{i=1}^{i=N}X_i - T| < \epsilon)$ $\leq f(E[X], Var[X], N, T)$. In this case, I want to figure out $f(\cdot)$ and crystallize the relationship between $N$ and $f(\cdot)$. Although it seems like the hoffding inequality, I am not sure how to fully incorporate $Var[X]$ and $T$ in $f(\cdot)$.

Please help me!

Comment: Can you rephrase your question, because what you're trying to minimize is a random variable?

Comment: Thank you very much for reaching out! I have updated it, and please let me know if you have any advice.

Comment: Hoeffding assumes bounds on the RV, Markov doesn't utilize the variance, and can't convert this into Chebyshev form. The only thing I can think of is approximating the sum via normal RVs.